# Will 1080i video capture card support 1080p @ 30hz camera?

Tags: video-capture, cctv

I've a CCTV camera with an analog 1080p @ 30hz output and am wondering if a 1080i video capture PC card will support it.

Since the camera's output is only 30hz, the 1080i video capture card (e.g. HVR-1265) should be powerful enough to process, because processing 1080i @ 60hz requires the same speed as processing 1080p @ 30hz, but since 1080p and 1080i formats are different and 1080i format has two fields (odd lines, even lines), I'm wondering if I could run into format incompatibilities issues.

Comment: What connection are you using between the capture card and the camera? Is it analog or digital? Analog will work, digital may not.

Comment: It's a composite output and input is fed to S-Video/Composite. It's analog: http://www.cctvimports.com/cbiv-1080p-2812-tvi. Thanks for your answer. I'll buy this one  tomorrow: http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hvr1265.html and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned hard way that it doesn't work. My video capture card, which is Hauppauge HVR-1600 does supports 1080i according to its spec. It worked somehow with a 1080p CCTV camera, but I could see two images instead of one that have been crossed by diagonal lines, so it was not very useful.

My next step would be to buy an HD-DVR, which does support HD Analog, connects to a PC through USB and produces an output encoded as H.264/MPEG.I'll let you know how it works.